# tvos: iTunesConnect Validation Fails for Alamofire Framework: does not contain bitcode

Tags: xcode, alamofire, tvos, bitcode, carthage

My tvOS App is failing validation after uploading to iTunesConnect for TestFlight distributions.

Validation fails with the following message:

> Invalid Executable - The executable 'MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' does not contain bitcode.

My Cartfile: `github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "tvOS"`.

I am using the release version of XCode 7.1. I don't see `ENABLE_BITCODE` for my tvOS target. (I assume bitcode is enabled for my target since it is mandatory for tvOS). Also, `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE` is set to `bitcode` for the Alamofire tvOS branch.

`otool -l Carthage/Build/tvOS/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire | grep LLVM` does return nothing. So, it does seem like I am missing bitcode support.

Things work fine on the simulator and on a real device.

How do I build a bitcode supported version of the Alamofire framework using Carthage so that it passes Apple server side validation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're submiting Framework with appletvsimulator in project settings. Check this link  [Carthage issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/824)